# Recursive checking for folder name per aggregate?

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, aggregate

I have following example documents: (`parent_id: null` means the file/folder is located at root directory)

```json
{"_id":"a", "name":"Pictures", "parent_id": null, "type": "folder"}
{"_id":"d", "name":"Paris", "parent_id":"b", "type": "folder"}
{"_id":"c", "name":"New Folder", "parent_id": null, "type": "folder"}
{"_id":"b", "name":"Vacation 2020", "parent_id":"a", "type": "folder"}
{"_id":"e", "name":"Videos", "parent_id": null, "type": "folder"}
{"_id":"f", "name": "Paris", "parent_id": null, "type": "folder"}
```

And I have a array containing value: (Basically same as `Pictures/Vacation 2020/Paris` or `Pictures > Vacation 2020 > Paris` as path)

```json
["Pictures", "Vacation 2020", "Paris"]
```

I want to see as final result:

```json
{"_id":"a", "name":"Pictures", "parent_id": null, "type": "folder"}
{"_id":"b", "name":"Vacation 2020", "parent_id":"a", "type": "folder"}
{"_id":"d", "name":"Paris", "parent_id":"b", "type": "folder"}
```

Is there a way, maybe in aggregate state, where it search for first

```json
// First Folder
"name": "Pictures"
"parent_id": null
```

which returns it to `{"_id":"a", "name":"Pictures", "parent_id": null, "type": "folder"}`
and then it will search for the next child folder:

```json
// Second Folder
"name": "Vacation 2020"
"parent_id": "a"
```

which will result returning to `{"_id":"b", "name":"Vacation 2020", "parent_id":"a", "type": "folder"}`. And then with the following final command:

```json
// Third Folder
"name": "Paris"
"parent_id": "b"
```

And then return all found documents (from final result) back to me?

I was thinking to use for-loop with findOne but it doesn't sound very effective as using aggregate function.

Does anybody have an idea? That would be great! Thanks!

DarkLordCoder

P.S. each folder has unique name on same parent_id. Hence you can have 2 folder named "Paris", but it has different parent_id (because they're located on different folder).

Answer (score 0):

I find that with the given requirements that the easiest way to accomplish the task was to first find the last item in the array. By doing this it's easier to grab the parents because we have the parent_id property.

The flow goes like this:

1. get last element in array (myArray)
2. find that item in the documents array (foundIem)
3. add the item to array (in addItemFindParent function)
4. if parent_id is present, get the item then recursively cal the addItemFindParent function

***UPDATED***

```
const documents = [
  { _id: 'a', name: 'Pictures', parent_id: null, type: 'folder' },
  { _id: 'b', name: 'Pictures', parent_id: 'g', type: 'folder' },
  { _id: 'c', name: 'Vacation 2020', parent_id: 'a', type: 'folder' },
  { _id: 'd', name: 'Vacation 2020', parent_id: 'b', type: 'folder' },
  { _id: 'e', name: 'Paris', parent_id: 'c', type: 'folder' },
  { _id: 'f', name: 'Paris', parent_id: 'd', type: 'folder' },
  { _id: 'g', name: 'Old Stuff', parent_id: null, type: 'folder' }
]

const myArray = ['Pictures', 'Vacation 2020', 'Paris']

const items = myArray.reduce((pv, cv) => {
  const foundItems = documents.filter(doc => doc.name === cv)
  if (foundItems.length) {
    pv.push(foundItems)
    return pv
  } else {
    throw new Error(`No items found for ${cv}`)
  }
}, [])

const findItems = items.reduce((parentPV, parentCV, parentIndex) => {
  if (parentIndex === 0) {
    parentCV = parentCV.filter(doc => !doc.parent_id)
    parentPV.push(parentCV)
    return parentPV
  } else {
    parentCV = parentCV.reduce((childPV, childCV, childIndex) => {
      const foundParent = parentPV.find(doc => doc._id === childCV.parent_id)
      if (foundParent) {
        childPV.push(childCV)
      }
      return childPV
    })
    parentPV.push(parentCV)
    return parentPV
  }
}, [])

console.log(findItems)
```

Comment: The reason why I'm using parent_id is to avoid name conflict. See as example "Paris". We have 2 Paris here but in different location. One "Paris" has "parent_id": null because it's on root directory. Other "Paris" is at "Pictures" > "Vacation 2020" > "Paris". the "parent_id": "b" in "Paris" means  the parent folder is "Vacation 2020" which has the _id: "b".

And "Vacation 2020" parent_id is "a" which is the Folder "Pictures" and so on.

Comment: Ok it should work for you now. I just added a recursive function that calls itself if there is a parent_id.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I was actually wishing for aggregate function, because this function can be very slow esp. if you're using a third party services like MongoDB Atlas.

Otherwise - it's a good solution which I had similar in my mind as well! Thank you!

Comment: Also this really don't solve it. 

Because there can be multiple "Paris" folder at different parent-folder (per parent_id). Meaning there can be 4 "Paris" Folder, but with different parent_id.

Comment: Looks like you have something in mind - please post you final code so I can see what you ended up doing. There's many ways to fix the paris folder issue and I can give you suggestions if you needed it. I was trying to lead you to the right spot not handle all use cases.

Comment: alright I updated. Still interested in what you end up using please post.